# Scaling in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

I am generating planar coordinates within the range (x,y) in [0,500]x[0,500]. When using `matplotlib.pyplot` to visualize them, the axes only show the part that contains already generated points. How can I scale the axes so that they correspond to [0,500]x[0,500]?

This is what I have for now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ax.set_xlim([0, 500])` and `set_ylim`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the row and column size of the plot area by the following..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,5)
```

But the *figure.figsize* accepts the parameter in inches, so if you need it to be in other units, then adjust the parameter by converting from inches to your desired unit.

Hope this helps.